# Is Grails missing support for http OPTIONS requests?

Tags: http, grails, url-mapping, http-options-method

When I create the grails 2.2.4 app below, I see responses to `POST /options/somewhere` but *not* to `OPTIONS /options/somewhere`.

Is there some way to invoke a controller action on OPTIONS requests?

---

App where `POST` works and `OPTIONS` doesn't:

```
$ grails create-app options
$ grails create-controller api
```

**UrlMappings.groovy**:

```
class UrlMappings {
  static mappings = {
    "/somewhere" (controller: "api", parseRequest: true) {
      action = [OPTIONS: "getOptions", POST: "saveStuff"]
    } 
  } 
}
```

**ApiController.groovy**:

```
package options

class ApiController {
    def getOptions() {
      render("Your options await.")
    }
    def saveStuff() {
      render("Stuff saved.")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 "/somewhere" (controller: "api", parseRequest: true) { //controller name begins with a lowercase letter
        action = [OPTIONS: "getOptions", POST: "saveStuff"]
    }
```

I use grails 2.0.3 and it do not work as I expected. But should work for latest grails version (2.3). Pls see related [bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-5531?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel).

Comment: It should. I need more information about your application. Can you provide your controller code and actual request url ?

Comment: I've updated my question to make this really explicit.  Can you confirm that this actually works for you?

Comment: I ll try as soon as i get to my job=)